# How to Create an MSI which runs in passive mode using WIX?

Tags: command-line, wix, windows-installer, mode, silent

How can I create an MSI using WIX that can run in passive mode?
If I double click on the msi it should launch in passive mode. This should be equivalent of running MSI package with `/passive` or `/qb!-` command line option. This is required to start the MSI installation from another application.

Is there any way of embedding command line options into MSI package?

Please post ideas that would help?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use UIRef to include any UI: If the .msi package doesn't have dialogs in it, MSI will run it with basic UI (the equivalent of /qb-).

Comment: This way I tried. If I run in basic UI mode (Without using any UI reference) the progress bar has "Cancel" button. I want the "Cancel" button also to be hide. (Equivalent of '/qb-!')